# Json Laravel Model

Tags: php, json, laravel, model

How to write model in Laravel without creating Database and with function getData that returns Json? Something like:

```
<?php 

namespace App; 

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model; 

class Table extends Model 
{ 
    protected $table = 'table'; 
    protected $fillable = [ 
        'atribute1', 
        'atribute2',
        'atribute3', 
        'atribute4' 
    ]; 
}
```

But without database.

I would be grateful for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to extend Model only if you're using Eloquent.

If you just need to get json data from somewhere, create usual class which gets data from somewhere and returns JSON:

```
class MyModel
{
    public function getJsonData()
    {
        $jsonData = // get json data from somewhere

        return $jsonData;
    }
}
```

Register this class in `composer.json` file, run `composer dumpauto` and use your class:

```
$model = new MyModel();
$data = $model->getJsonData();
```